# Why is Koa's redirect throwing 404 after another redirect?

Tags: javascript, koa, koa2

I have the following code...

```
const auth = new Authentication();
mainApp.use(auth.checkToken.bind(auth));
mainApp.use(mount('/auth', auth.app));

class Authentication{
    constructor() {
        this.redirectApp = new Koa();
        this.redirectApp.use(this.onLogin);
        this.logoutApp = new Koa();
        this.logoutApp.use(this.onLogout);
        this.callbackApp = new Koa();
        this.callbackApp.use(this.onCallback);
        this.app = new Koa();
        this.app.use(mount('/login', this.redirectApp));
        this.app.use(mount('/callback', this.callbackApp));
        this.app.use(mount('/logout', this.logoutApp));
    }
    checkToken(ctx, next){
        if(ctx.path  === "/auth/login" || ctx.path  === "/auth/callback" || ctx.path === "/auth/logout"){
            next();
        } else{
            const cookie = ctx.cookies.get("userInfo");
            if(cookie == null){
                ctx.redirect("/auth/login");
            } else{
                const userInfo = JSON.parse(ctx.cookies.get("userInfo"));
                if(userInfo.accessToken){
                    // TODO: check the token;
                    next();
                } else{
                    ctx.redirect("/auth/login");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    onLogin(ctx){
        const path = `https://${domain}/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&scope=email&audience=${audience}&state=`;
        ctx.redirect(path);
    }
}
```

When I go to the root (http://localhost:3000) I can see it hit the `ctx.redirect(path);` but I get a 404. If I comment out `mainApp.use(auth.checkToken.bind(auth));` and hit `/auth/login` directly it works fine.

Why can I not do a redirect after the initial middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with an await on next...

```
async checkToken(ctx, next){
    if(ctx.path  === "/auth/login" || ctx.path  === "/auth/callback" || ctx.path === "/auth/logout"){
        await next();
    } else{
        const cookie = ctx.cookies.get("userInfo");
        if(cookie == null){
            ctx.redirect("/auth/login");
        } else{
            const userInfo = JSON.parse(ctx.cookies.get("userInfo"));
            if(userInfo.accessToken){
                // TODO: check the token;
                await next();
            } else{
                ctx.redirect("/auth/login");
            }
        }
    }
}
```